# How to edit get_bloginfo('template_directory') to localhost instead of real domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I trying to install WordPress website to my local directory.

`get_bloginfo('template_directory')` returns me `http://realdomain.com` instead of `localhost`.

How and where do i change it?

Answer (score 2):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://siteurl'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://siteurl');
```

put this two line in your wp-config.php file

Answer (score 1):

You need to update home and siteurl in the options table.

Comment: I just did it but nothing happens - when i go to admin panel it still sends me to real domain...

Comment: In the admin panel under Settings -> General are the fields disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in `settings > general` But you may want to take caution when doing this.